# Connect multiple commands via pipe in a shell variable

Tags: pipeline, bash

What I want to do is:

```
>STRIPPER='sed s/admin_editable=\"[01]\"// | sed s/runtime_editable=\"[01]\"//'
>cat file.txt | $STRIPPER > stripped.txt
```

i.e. define a shell variable which is a pipeline of multiple commands (mine happen to be `sed`'s), that I can then call later.  I'm doing this from the command line now, but may ultimately put it into a script.

I've tried both ' and " for enclosing the command neither works.

```
sed: can't read |: No such file or directory
sed: can't read sed: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/admin_editable=\"[01]\"//: No such file or directory
sed: can't read |sed: No such file or directory
sed: can't read s/runtime_editable=\"[01]\"//: No such file or directory
sed: can't read |: No such file or directory
```

I know that there is probably a single regex that could handle this case, but I'd like to know how to do the pipeline in general.

Comment: Pipelines are part of the shell's grammar, and as such are recognized before any parameter expansion takes place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a great place to use a function rather than a variable.

```
stripper() {
    sed s/admin_editable="[01]"// | sed s/runtime_editable="[01]"//
}

cat file.txt | stripper > stripped.txt
```

You could also eliminate the useless use of cat:

```
stripper < file.txt > stripped.txt
```